# Does the execution have to keep stopping to set a breakpoint?

Tags: go, debugging, visual-studio-code, delve

1. vscode@1.60.0
2. vscode-go@v0.27.2
3. go:1.16.3 darwin/amd64

Hello I am developing api with gin.

Whenever I add a breakpoint to the http handler, a `Execution halted to set breakpoints - please resume execution manually` is being output to the debug console.

When developing an API, it is quite common to check breakpoints in handlers.
Because you can see how the request came and the logic behaved and responded as intended.

But every time I check and uncheck a breakpoint, I have to mechanically press Continue Debug.
This greatly reduces development productivity.

It didn't happen before, but it seems to be happening with a recent update.
Is this the intended behavior?

##### Additional confirmed points

I was able to figure out what was causing the above issue by checking the release notes.

The `dlv-dap` added in [Release 0.27.0](https://github.com/golang/vscode-go/releases/tag/v0.27.0) is identified as the cause of the problem. Using the [legacy debug adapter](https://github.com/golang/vscode-go/blob/master/docs/debugging-legacy.md#selecting-legacy-debug-adapter) does not cause the above problem.

I can't seem to see what was raised above for known issues with dlv-dap. Is this behavior normal? Or is it still in development?

Answer (score 1):

Your understanding is correct - there is an open issue in https://github.com/golang/vscode-go/issues/1648 The Delve DAP team is currently looking into a way to address this issue.

Background: While transitioning to the new debug adapter, the delve DAP team was trying to preserve the legacy debug adapter's behavior. However, they encountered some technical challenges. The legacy debug adapter holds the similar underlying issues but they were unnoticed because the legacy debug adapter was developed independently and never reviewed by delve dev team.